# Merging case types in CiviCase

Tags: civicase

I would like to consolidate the case types that I have created for CiviCase.

Is there a way to merge two or more case types into a broader category so that the cases once assigned to these more narrow case types can assume the new, broader case type?

Comment: How many cases are we talking about converting?

Comment: We currently have 21 case types. We want to reduce this number to 9 by deleting a few and combining the rest. Some of the new case types we want to create may incorporate up to 3 existing case types.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a way in the user interface but if you're comfortable with directly accessing the database and don't need to update any timelines/activities you can do something like:

```
UPDATE civicrm_case SET case_type_id = CONCAT(CHAR(1), '8', CHAR(1)) WHERE case_type_id = CONCAT(CHAR(1), '1', CHAR(1));
```

This would take the ones who have case type 1 and convert them to 8. You'd have to look and see what the existing numbers are:

```
select ov.label, ov.value from civicrm_option_group og inner join civicrm_option_value ov on (ov.option_group_id = og.id and og.name = 'case_type');
```

And of course do this on a test site first, and make a backup.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.

Comment: If I use PHPMyAdmin, where to I plug in the above script? Or do I use another program?

Comment: You can do this with any program that allows you to access the MySQL database (including the command terminal) but certainly with PHPMyAdmin!